# What is the exact translation of "Frusta me natum"

Tags: meaning, sentence-translation

This is a popular Cicero's sentence from the book *de Senectute*, chap. 23:

> ita vixi ut non frusta me natum existimem

whose translation is accepted as something like "I lived in such way that I reckon I wasn't born pointlessly"

The middle construction is the weird part to me.

"*Frusta*", as far as I know, comes from "*Frustum*" which means pieces, debris, portions of food [source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frustum#Latin).

"*natum*" is probably the supine (accusative of passive participle) of "*nascor*" (I am born), deponent verb.

and well, "me" is me. So how can *Frusta me natum* mean "I wasn't born pointlessly" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mistyped it. The word in question is actually [*frust**r**a*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfrustra), and is an adverb meaning "in vain" or, as that translator put it, "pointlessly."

The sentence is indirect speech within the apodosis of a result clause. Verbs of thinking (thus *existimo*), saying, believing, etc. introduce an accusative + infinitive construction as the dependent clause: I believe (*existimem*) that I (*me*) was born (*natum*, with esse dropped) not in vain (*non frustra*).

Minor note: the accusative of the passive participle is not the same thing as the supine. They may look identical in the accusative singular, but a participle is a verbal adjective, and thus can decline according to the subject, whereas a supine is a verbal noun. If this were a female speaker, it would have been *natam* not *natum*.